# RangeError: Invalid typed array length: -4095 when running my react web app

Tags: reactjs, npm

When I try to run the application using `HTTPS=true npm start` command got the below error:

> RangeError: Invalid typed array length: -4095 when running my react web app

However I was able to run the application using `npm start`

Error - `

```
internal/buffer.js:788
class FastBuffer extends Uint8Array {}
^

RangeError: Invalid typed array length: -4095
    at new Uint8Array (<anonymous>)
    at new FastBuffer (internal/buffer.js:788:1)
    at Handle.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:153:17)
    at Stream.<anonymous> (/Users/kithma/Documents/wellbee/wb-web/node_modules/handle-thing/lib/handle.js:120:12)
    at Stream.emit (events.js:198:15)
    at endReadableNT (/Users/kithma/Documents/wellbee/wb-web/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:1010:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:17)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! wb-web@0.1.0 start: `react-app-rewired start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the wb-web@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.`
```

Comment: your Node version ? this problem for Node >=11.1.0 , when downgrade to 10.x then fix

Comment: I got this error too. Node version: 12.14.1. Did you manage to fix it @Kithma ?

Answer (score 3):

Despite the fact that the fix below was made not for React, I think it could do a trick for React too as it seems the problem again in the old version of the package `handle-thing` which is probably used by some dependency.

As the first step please check that guess with a command `npm list handle-thing`  and if it outputs not the latest version of `handle-thing` you can try a solution below.

My situation:

npm list handle-thing gives me `handle-thing@1.2.5` which is a dependency of old `angular/cli` which I cannot update for now.

Also, I cannot use `yarn` to override package resolutions, fix below has worked for me:

1. install `https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-force-resolutions`
   do not forget scripts / preinstall step
2. add/modify that section into package.json:

   "resolutions": {
   "handle-thing": "^2.0.1"
   }
3. `make npm install`
4. start your web app in SSL mode

Tested with node v14.13.1

The solution is taken from the discussion https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/24097

Comment: This worked for me and I still was able to use yarn.  Was at v 1.22.5 at the time.  Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading your react & react-scripts dependencies should resolve this issue.
For me after bumping `"react": "^16.13.1"` and `"react-scripts": "^3.4.1"` the problem went away. I'm also using node v12 FYI.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Next.js` with webpack `v. 5.x` you may try to downgrade webpack to `v. 4.x` (in my case it helped).

Just add to **next.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
 // next.config.js
  webpack5: false,
}
```